# Trying to pull data and input it into a drop-down menu but it doesn't seem to pull anything? Am I missing something?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the connection etc previous to this; the column I'm trying to pull is called course_name from database course - not sure if I'm missing something?

```
        <label for="course">Related Course</label>
        <select name="course" class="form-control">

        <?php 

        $result = mysql_query($conn, "SELECT course_name FROM course");

        echo "<select name='course_name'>";
        if (!$result) { 
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        } else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['course_name'] ."'>" . $row['course_name'] ."</option>";
                }
        }
        echo "</select>";

        ?>

        </select>
```

Comment: Typo: `mysql_fetch_array($result1)`

Comment: @cteski Do not advise OP on how to create security issues. Please do not use `mysql_*` functions

Comment: Thanks, I've updated this but still doesn't seem to pull anything!

Comment: @Akintunde007 I've advised nothing of the sort, I simply pointed out the obvious typo. Carry on.

Comment: Does `mysql_error()` give an error? What is it?

Comment: oh I've just checked within devs and it says 'Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string' @AaronGarton

Comment: Please understand that using mysql_ functions is not secure!
Please use mysqli_ functions or PDO statements.

Comment: @Thomas: The first parameter needs to be a string, aka your query (src: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your comments below you are using mysqli not mysql php extension, so your code should look like this

```
   <?php 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT course_name FROM course");

    echo "<select name='course_name'>";
    if (!$result) { 
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    } else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['course_name'] ."'>" . $row['course_name'] ."</option>";
            }
    }
    echo "</select>";

    ?>
```

Comment: I've changed it to this now i'm getting this error - Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource

Comment: do you have something like $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass'); ?

Comment: I've got into in another file and included it within this file at the top, i have: 

<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'databasename');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "<p>Connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error()."</p>\n";
}


?>

Comment: ok but you are mixing two different PHP extensions mysql and mysqli, from what you've paste above you're DB connection is using mysqli_connect() but then you are trying to query the DB with mysql_query() you should use the mysqli_query() function instead

Comment: ok I've changed them to mysqli functions and I'm now getting - Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in  

this is on line 64 -     die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());

Comment: you need to pass $conn to mysqli_error() like this mysqli_error($conn)

Comment: also take 5 min to read the docs for each function, it goes a LONG way ;)

Comment: Haha I think I need to! I'm now getting this error - Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given. They're never ending lol

Comment: yes because mysql_query vs mysqli_query have the parameters reversed :) so you're code in the original question was good, just the "i" was missing from all mysql_ functions, because u did not post the connection to DB i assumed u used mysql_connect not mysqli_connect, hope it makes sense

Comment: Oh thanks! I've had a read and I've now got data reading from it just not into the drop down - will let you know how i've got on. Thanks for the help!

Comment: cool, if will help please accept / upvote my answer, and good luck i feel you're just starting with programming :)